# Save Account action in Lightning Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-community, custom-actions, lightning-action-override

I am working on creating a Lightning Community. There's this **My Account** page where **a logged in community user** can view & update the Account Record information attached with their User Profile such as Account Name, Phone Number, Address, etc.
When community user edits and saves the account, everything works fine except for the account page layout in the community. I have setup a specific account page layout for Account for community users, This Lightning Record Page has only one region with Account details, no Related list and no Chatter feeds. But **as soon as I edit and save the account info**, the **page layout changes** and starts displaying the related page tab and chatter feed tab. and the url of the page also changes from **/my-account** to **/details/[sfdc-id]**

At this point I have checked everything in Community Experience Builder & Salesforce Lightning Page Layout Assignments but I can't figure out this issue. Can someone explain what might be going on here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer regarding making an object page specifically for `Account` is correct. If you want that much control over the Account detail page, you will need to make a set of object pages for Account so that the Account records aren't displaying the Generic Object pages in the Community.

1. In the Experience Builder you want to click on the *Pages* dropdown in the top left and then select "+ New Page".
2. Select "Object Pages"
3. Find your object (e.g. Account, Case) and select "Create". Salesforce, by default, will inform you that this action creates a Detail, List, and Related List page in the community.
   [image: Account Pages]

Now, on your new Detail page you can control what components the user will see. If you want to remove the standard record layout, you can remove the "Record Information Tabs" component (which should be the default on a record Detail page) and replace it with whatever components you have in your arsenal.

If you also want to replace what users see with standard Edit action, you can provide an override for the Edit action. Bear in mind that this will override the Edit action for *everyone* in your Salesforce org. If you need a particularly robust solution, you can override the Edit action with a Lightning component that makes a determination for what to display to the user based on their profile/license and then show a different modal for Community users vs standard licensed users. This is an unfortunate hoop that you need to jump through because, so long as the user's object permissions include **Edit**, they will always have access to the standard Edit action.

If you only want users to interface with Accounts via your custom community page and component, then you will need to avoid record navigation actions and I would imagine, set up a component on the Account detail page to redirect users that stumble upon it over to your `my-account` page.